# I want to detect the date in a stamp on an image of a postcard, how should I go about it?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, ocr

I have a bit of a particular problem that I'm trying to tackle. 
I have some postcard images like this:

[image: example1]
[image: example2]

I want to recognize the text inside the circle stamp, specifically the year. As you can see, it's also possible for the numbers to be kind of faded away or maybe missing a little ink in some places. Furthermore, we can also have the stamp overlapping with text. But for the simplest case, I want to assume first that the text is within reasonable readability.

My question is what would be the most efficient way to tackle this problem?

The approaches I've considered thus far are of two types. Either we can find the circle or we can directly try to identify digits in the image. Everything is really preliminary because I'm not sure which direction would be best to go yet.

Let's say we want to find the circle first. So far I've considered:

1. Contouring using opencv. I am really new to this so I just briefly read about how to do it. For example, I binarized an image: 
   [image: Imgur]
   The various specks (I guess you can call them?) are actually the parts where the ink in the handwriting came off thicker, as you can see in the image below: 
   [image: Imgur]
   Since the text can be as dark as the stamp, I'm thinking that maybe black and white is not the way to go. This brings me to strategy number 2.
2. Use color threshold to distinguish stamp from handwriting and other printed text. When looking at a few images of postcards with stamp, I noticed that it's usually a certain faded black color? But I don't know if this would help me.
3. Detect circles using Houghtransform. I briefly tried this but my concern is that this would be too slow?

The other approach as mentioned would be to directly identify the digits. But somehow I feel like I would still need a bounding box for this?? So that just leads me back to the first strategy.

I really appreciate any input or opinions you may have on this! I realize that it is a pretty complex problem (at least for a beginner), and I was just wondering if there was any advice on what would be the best use of time. Thank you!

Comment: sorry I am trying to fix imgur links right now

Comment: `3. Detect circles using Houghtransform` <- do this. Why would this be too slow?

Comment: Thank you! I just tried that. You are right that it is not too slow. I will work on this and see if I can make some improvements.